# SQL Server Full text search error

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, procedure

In my stored procedure, when a long word is passed, server shows error, with part of the word.

I am not sure what is happening .. the word seems to break, but I have given a big value for that variable

[image]

My procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_BuyOnlineSearchNew]-- '1','BMW X6 IN GOOD CONDITION FOR SALE','0','0'       
    @CategoryID varchar(20),
    @SearchString varchar(max),
    @RecentAd int,
    @RowsPerPage INT, 
    @PageNumber INT,
    @pricefrom INT,
    @priceto INT,
    @categories Varchar(2000),
    @advancesearch varchar(2000),
    @features varchar(2000),
    @technicalfeatures varchar(2000),
    @CompanyID varchar(20)
AS            
BEGIN            
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @OffetCount as int = (@PageNumber-1)*4

Select TotalCount = COUNT(CM.BuyOnlineID) OVER(),
    CM.BuyOnlineID,cm.OfferPrice,cm.[Description], CM.Title,CONVERT(VARCHAR, [CM].[DatePosted],106) AS 'DatePosted',
    CM.Price, 
    CM.isActive,            
    CM.GoogleLocation,  
    CM.IsImageVerified,
    Row_Number() Over ( Order By CM.BuyOnlineID desc ) As Rownumber,
    CM.AreaID,

    (select top 1 image from [tblBuyOnlineImages] where BuyOnlineID=CM.BuyOnlineID) As imagepath,
    (select count(*) from [tblBuyOnlineImages] where BuyOnlineID=CM.BuyOnlineID) As imagecount,
    CM.categorytreename
    FROM [dbo].[tblBuyOnlineMaster] AS CM 

  WHERE 

     (CONTAINS(CM.CategoryTreename, @categories))

        order by CM.BuyOnlineID  OFFSET @OffetCount ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY

SET NOCOUNT OFF              

END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s Ok, I will keep it in mind

Comment: Any idea about why the word is partly selected and error shows

Comment: " I have given a big value for that variable"  nvarchar(7) is big???

Comment: @Aツ ,thanks man.....  got it , I havent looked there

Comment: @Aツ but that was autogenerated by the profiler