# sql server Full text search not supporting 'for' keyword

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

My test data

Bed & Bath | Bath Accessories | Towel | 
Décor & Accessories | Candles & Candleholders | 
Gifts & Gadgets | For Her |

```
@categories='"candles & Candleholders"'        works 

@categories='"Bath Accessories"'               works 

@categories='"For Her"'                     doesn't work 

@categories='"For"'                       doesn't work
```

It looks like the word 'for' is not supported or something, how to solve this

Comment: Is it related to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38763152/2451726) ?

Comment: @Rinto Antony  The 'For' is a reserved keyword. you could remove it from the stopwords list.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583(v=sql.110).aspx)

> When defining a full-text query, the Full-Text Engine discards
>   stopwords (also called noise words) from the search criteria.
>   Stopwords are words such as "a," "and," "is," or "the," that can occur
>   frequently but that typically do not help when searching for
>   particular text. Stopwords are listed in a stoplist. Each full-text
>   index is associated with a specific stoplist, which determines what
>   stopwords are omitted from the query or the index at indexing time.
>   For more information, see Configure and Manage Stopwords and Stoplists
>   for Full-Text Search.

I guess `For` is a stopword too. Check out this [page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551(v=sql.110).aspx) of MSDN to configure stopwords.